# InvocationTargetException em método dinâmico

Tags: java, cdi

Estou com uma situação muito estranha.

Recebo do meu `Bean` os seguintes argumentos:

```
#{segurancaBean.callSubAcaoMethod(subAcao, moduloBean.class.name, modulo.id)}
```

Esta método é dinâmico:

```
public void callSubAcaoMethod(Acao acao, String bean, Long id){
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(bean);
        Method method = clazz.getMethod(acao.getTipoAcao().getNmBean(), Long.class);
        Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
        Object ins = new Object();
        ins = method.invoke(obj, id);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SegurancaBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

**Deste método eu vou receber:**
Nome do meu método genérico
Nome da minha classe para instância dinâmica
ID do objeto que virá da `view`

E abaixo é o método que será utilizado:

```
@Override
public void btnAlterar(Long id){
    Modulo m = new Modulo();
    m = moduloServico.pesquisar(id);
}
```

Agora vem a parte estranha.

Se neste meu método ou colocar um `System.out.println("alguma mensagem")` ou `Modulo m = new Modulo();` ou *printar na tela o ID que recebo de parâmetro* funciona normalmente!
Agora quando eu vou fazer qualquer operação relacionada a instanciar um objeto, eu tenho o erro:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

A linha `m = moduloServico.pesquisar(id);` é um exemplo que gera este erro.

Em detalhe, coloquei na minha `view` também um botão direto que acessa o método sem passar pelo `callSubAcaoMethod` e funciona normal! Eu consigo instanciar e fazer tudo o que quiser, ou seja, não seria problema do meu serviço.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido.

Por estar usando CDI, fiz o "newInstance" por este método:

```
Object obj = CDI.current().select(clazz).get();
```